# How to return HTTP response through subsequent service call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise, angular-services

I am facing problem in returning data from Web API to Angular Form  via series of Common Function. I am giving the code in its simplest form to understand the problem:-

**HTML Form:-**

```
<label>Request Number</label>
<input type="text" id="txtRequestNum" ng-model="md_reqnumber" />
<label>Employee Number</label>
<input type="text" id="txtEmployeeId" ng-model="md_number" ng-disabled="true" />
```

**Controller.js**

```
var myApp = angular.module('appHome');
myApp.controller("ctrlEmployeeAdd", ['$scope', 'CommonFunctionFactory', function ($scope,  CommonFunctionFactory) {
    CommonFunctionFactory.AddMasterData($scope.md_reqnumber)
        .then(function (dataSuccess) {
            $scope.number = dataSuccess;
        }, function (dataError) {
        });
}]);
```

**CommonFunctionFactory.js**

```
var appService = angular.module('appHome');
appService.factory('CommonFunctionFactory', ['MetadataOrgFactory', function (MetadataOrgFactory) {
    var dataFactory = {};

    dataFactory.AddMasterData = function (objData) {
        MetadataOrgFactory.postApiCall('addemployee', objData, function (dataSuccess) {
            alert("The request has been completed succesfully");
            return dataSuccess; 
        }, function (dataError) {
        });
    }
    return dataFactory;
}])
```

**ApiCallService.js**

```
var appService = angular.module('appHome');
appService.factory('MetadataOrgFactory', ['$http', '$q', function ($http, $q) {
    var dataFactory = {};
    var url = 'http://localhost:XXXXX';

    dataFactory.postApiCall = function (controllerName, objData, callbackSuccess, callbackError) {

        $http.post(url + '/api/' + controllerName, objData).then
            (function success(response) {
                alert("Success");
                callbackSuccess(response.data);
            }, function error(response) {
                callbackError(response.status);
            });
    };

    return dataFactory;
}])
```

**WebApi.cs**

```
[Authorize]
[Route("api/addemployee")]
[HttpPost]
public int AddEmployee(EmployeeViewModel vmEmployee)
{
    return 54302 //Just for simplicity here, returning hard coded value
}
```

I am able to get the above hard coded value in **ApiCallService.js** and also able to get in the **datasuccess** variable of **CommonFunctionFactory.js** but not able to return the value back to **Controller.js**. This is my actual problem here.

Also angular promise defined in **Controller.js** is giving following error after getting the response from Web API:-

> Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Please help me in solving the problem.

Comment: `AddMasterData` doesn't return anything. Why would you expect it's return value (undefined) to have a .then method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As AnthW pointed out, you are pretty close, but I think your issues revolve around what you are and aren't returning. My changes are below, it doesn't require changing your `controller.js` or server files, only the two factories.

**CommonFunctionFactory.js**

For this, I would personally remove this factory, but if you want to keep it, I would just return the $http call and this way in your controller you can use `then` and access the returned variable.

```
var appService = angular.module('appHome');
appService.factory('CommonFunctionFactory', ['MetadataOrgFactory', function (MetadataOrgFactory) {
    var dataFactory = {};

    dataFactory.AddMasterData = function (objData) {
        return MetadataOrgFactory.postApiCall('addemployee', objData);
    }
    return dataFactory;
}])
```

**ApiCallService.js**

As AnthW pointed out in his answer, you aren't returning the $http call, which is why you are seeing undefined. Also, there is no reason to use callback functions when you are using promises, promises are just a different way to handle the same use case. In this code, I am removing your callbacks and we are returning the promise, and the promise is returning either the success object or the error object.

```
var appService = angular.module('appHome');
appService.factory('MetadataOrgFactory', ['$http', '$q', function ($http, $q) {
    var dataFactory = {};
    var url = 'http://localhost:XXXXX';

    dataFactory.postApiCall = function (controllerName, objData) {

        var promise = $http.post(url + '/api/' + controllerName, objData)
            .then(function(response) {
                alert("Success");
                return response.data;
            }, function(response) {
                return response.status;
            });

        return promise;
    };

    return dataFactory;
}])
```

So, in conclusion, my changes are to have your `ApiCallService.js` return the promise created by `$http`. The `CommonFunctionFactory.js` will just handle return this promise to the controller. In your controller, you are already expecting a promise, so this returned promise will then be properly accessed in your controller, and you will be able to retrieve the returned value.

Comment: The answer will work but then there will be changes in my structure. I have managed to get bypass of this situation. But anyways thanks for the answer.

Answer (score -1):

The `postApiCall` function is not returning anything. You need to return `$http`:

```
dataFactory.postApiCall = function (controllerName, objData, callbackSuccess, callbackError) {
  return $http.post(url + '/api/' + controllerName, objData)
    .then(function success(response) {
      alert("Success");
      callbackSuccess(response.data);
    },
    function error(response) {
      callbackError(response.status);
    });
};
```

You will then need to do the same with `MetadataOrgFactory.postApiCall` by adding a return in front of it:

```
return MetadataOrgFactory.postApiCall('addemployee', objData, function (dataSuccess) {
  alert("The request has been completed succesfully");
  return dataSuccess; 
  },
  function (dataError) {}
);
```

Now, you have returned the request so that calling `CommonFunctionFactory.AddMasterData($scope.md_reqnumber)` will have a `then` method available.

I imagine that it was just returning undefined previously. You can check by logging out the value of `CommonFunctionFactory.AddMasterData($scope.md_reqnumber)`

Comment: It was still returning "Cannot read property 'then' of undefined" error whhen I am using "then" at CommonFunctionFactory.AddMasterData. Can you please provide working example in Plunker please.